# Apos acionar um servico de download de pdf no jmeter, o response "mal formatado" pode virar um pdf? Se sim, como?

Tags: rest, soap, testes, jmeter

Estou trabalhando em um stress test onde realizo o download de um arquivo, em um servico GET bem simples:

/api/report/XXXXXXXX/user/23452/file/9989/download

Tudo ocorre OK, gostaria de saber se o response do download, que vem com caracteres do tipo "ÅßN-&ë·Úñï", é passivel de ser baixado o arquivo pdf pelo Jmeter?

Obs: Este servico tambem tem uma versao SOAP, nele eu consegui decodificar o base64 e baixar o .pdf pelo BeanShell PostProcessor no java.

Porem a estrutura e retorno do rest nao me proporciona isto. Gostaria de saber se posso conseguir baixar o .pdf a partir do response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode salvar a resposta de uma solicitação HTTP em um arquivo usando Salvar respostas em um ouvinte de arquivos.

Para a solicitação get, inclua um respone de salvaguarda no listener de arquivos e insira o prefixo do Nome do Arquivo. Por padrão, o JMeter salva o arquivo no diretório bin.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode ver um arquivo pdf é salvo no diretório bin.

A melhor maneira de executar os testes é usar a nuvem. [Leia este artigo](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/jmeter/) para executar testes na nuvem da AWS

Comment: obrigado amigo, perfeito ! era o que eu precisava.